# how to setup webroot for new ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, letsencrypt, certbot

I am setting up a new server and installing certbot on ubuntu 20.

I am confused with `sudo certbot certonly --webroot` command of certbot.

While running the command, it asks me input the webroot for domain.com.

What should I put here?

Note that it's a fresh ubuntu server and nothing else is installed except docker and certbot.

Comment: So why do you want to install SSL certificates if you do not have (yet) a website?

Comment: The purpose is to host a website

Comment: So, do the website and then the SSL certificates. The reason: when you decide for the website, you will decide where to put it (so webroot) and many other things. Then this question will be easier for you. But now you do not have a website, so no structure for webroot (and I experct you will use virtual domains, so you have to choose the root)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certbot is a program to automatically create and renew SSL certificates for your domain name from Let's Encrypt CA. In order for it to be useful, you need to already have:

1. a website set up and ready to serve HTTPS (to begin with, it can also be a single "hello world" webpage as a placeholder)
2. a FQDN for the website, thatis, you must have registered your own domain name

The webroot is the directory containing the web content (HTML files, etc.) of your website; usually it's `/var/www/html` or a subdir of it.

Comment: I don't see this directory by default in Ubuntu.